# Making static reference variable nullify will ever be garbage collected by java?

Tags: java, android

I have a question that looks very easy and simple but I am bit confused. My question is, in Android application I am making static reference of activity for some purposes. And in onDestroy() I am making that activity reference null while assigning null value explicitly. Is it good? Will it be eligible for garbage collection? will it also cause memory leak? Please help me in this regard.

This is the code I am using for activity reference in onCreate() method

```
mInstance = this;
```

And this is how in onDestroy() I am assigning null value

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mInstance = null;
}
```

Comment: DO NOT MAKE STATIC ACTIVITY REFERENCES.  There is no good reason to have a static copy of your Activity like that.  If you think you need it, you're misarchitecting your app.  Remember that there can be multiple copies of an Activity in existance at any time, so this technique will not work correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I 100% agree. I have got the code in that I have found many time activity static references in many activities. My question was if I assign null value to references in ondestroy method will it be eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: An object is eligible for collection if there is no path from a garbage collection root object to a variable.  So having a static reference to something would make it inelligible, as a a static variable is  a gc root.  Setting it to null would remove that single reason for inelligibility, but it still could be inelligible for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you nullify it will be garbage collected, but **assigning an Activity to a static variable is an anti-pattern and must be avoided at all costs**, even if you eventually nullify it, because this is easiest way to leak an Activity.

In fact, Android Studio should already be giving you a warning about it.

Here you have some [literature](http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html) to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: Your answer added some of the valueable suggestions. Thank you for directing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an Android developer, so I'll answer your question without taking into account that.

Yes, the space allocated by your `Activity` in the heap will be collected (*may be collected*) once no more references to it exists. Like every other object in Java.

Being `static` or not doesn't change that.

---

Although honestly I don't understand why

```
mInstance = this;
```

Could you explain in more details?
This isn't thread safe at all, so be careful if you're working on a concurrent environment.

Comment: mInstance basically the reference of the activity...you can consider an activity a class in java

Comment: @AnonymounslyDone I know, I know. I understood what you're doing. I edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

People will hate me for this but in my own modular architecture i like to use them on android. Yes it is a memory leak if you do not use them properly but it saves time and time means $$$ in my book. When i need to parse a Java Object from an activity to another activity there is diferent options. putExtra(JsonString), putExtra(Parseable), putExtra(Serializable). But i just like to create a new static file to hold all the objects i need temporary with a static public function to nullify all of them after getting them in the other activity. Be carefull if you do this.